# Disable application taskbar icon's context menu in Windows 8.0 and 8.1

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, contextmenu, taskbar

In Windows 7, 8 and 8.1, when a user right-clicks on an application's taskbar icon, a context menu appears. Furthermore, a user can right-click on the application's name again (from the context menu) and another context menu appears, as shown in this image for Windows Explorer:

[image]

Is there a possible way (through winapi or registry or GPO) to disable all the items in the first context menu except for "Close Window" in Win 8 and 8.1? I know that this is achieved in Windows 7 by setting the prevent pinning on the application window but it doesn't work in Windows 8 and 8.1...

If not, is it possible to show only the "Close Window" and the Application Launcher icon only in the context menu in Windows 8/8.1 **without** allowing the user to right-click on the application's name and display the Properties context menu?

Comment: I think your only option might be to stop the icon appearing on the taskbar in the first place. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve - why stop the user doing those things?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I'm working on a kiosk mode application that needs to offer more features than the Kiosk-mode feature of Windows 8 / 8.1. I need to keep the taskbar, the tray icon and also the application icons appearing on the taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this registry value which does the job well:

NoViewContextMenu: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960925.aspx